# VScode Mac "Cannot find /opt/homebrew"

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, boost, homebrew

I've been tying all say to set up a link to Boost and other libraries installed via Homebrew. I accessed the VScode settings UI via cmd + shift + P and entered the following into `Include path`:

> ${opt/homebrew}/**

Only to get

[image]

I can't think of any other way to set up a link to my path. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt there is a VSCode variable named `opt/homebrew` that seems odd. I assume you didn't recognize the  `${variableName}` syntax used. Maybe you just wanted to specify `/opt/homebrew/**` instead?

Comment: Hmm so will that link to homebrew?

Edit: works but doesn't link to the header files stil...